# BitviseSSH "The public key supplied has been verified;requesting signature."

Tags: ssh, bitvise

The key pair has been generated, the `known_hosts` and the `authorized_keys` has also been modified.The debug log show below.

```
$ ssh GitUser@192.168.1.108 -v
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.108 [192.168.1.108] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/hp/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/hp/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/hp/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/hp/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/hp/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/hp/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/hp/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/hp/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 7.29 FlowSsh: Bitvise SSH Server (WinSSHD) 7.29: free only for personal non-commercial use
debug1: no match: 7.29 FlowSsh: Bitvise SSH Server (WinSSHD) 7.29: free only for personal non-commercial use
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.108:22 as 'GitUser'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 SHA256:fdF60f1haCGRDRDQANgtjYotvsM6Zutd4/XHGjY0p6c
debug1: Host '192.168.1.108' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/hp/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-1.3.132.0.10,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/hp/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.108 ([192.168.1.108]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
shell request failed on channel 0
```

what should I do with the signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Authenticated to 192.168.1.108 ([192.168.1.108]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
shell request failed on channel 0
```

The authentication finished successfully, but the server was unable to respond to your shell request. It says that the server is configured wrong so you should have to look into the server log, what are the startup scripts for the remote user, what is his default shell and so on.

Comment: I restored the server configuration it works.And I checked the shell and root dir. It's the same as former.Would a proxy setting affect it?

Comment: No, it should not.